# How to avoid deleting priority_queue::top() despite a pop()?

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

The interface of STL and boost priority queues includes

```
T const &   top () const;
void    pop ();
```

The latter deletes the top element.  But what if I want to keep using that element after I pop() it, and I want to avoid copying?  E.g., suppose I have a `priority_queue<T> pq`.  I'd like to write

```
const T& first = pq.top();      
pq.pop();
const T& second = pq.top();
analyze(second);
analyze(first);      // first *after* second
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I pop(), the first reference becomes invalid, so I get a segfault.

I'd prefer a solution like java's `nextElement()`, which  returns `top()` and does a `pop()`, but deletes the element only when it goes out of scope.  That way I don't need to keep track of what to `pop()` and when.  However, using `priority_queue<shared_pointer<T> >` doesn't seem to help, because taking a ref to a `shared_pointer` doesn't increase its use_count.

In case it matters, I prefer to use `boost::fibonacci_heap` for its efficient `push()`.

Any ideas or pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you not simply call `analyze` before you `.pop`?

Comment: No.  I might be able to `analyze(first)` before I `pop()`, but the point is I need access to first **after** I `analyze(second)`, which I can't access before I `pop()` the first.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I don't think there's a good way around this, other than copying. Is copying a big problem?

Comment: You could use a bare vector and manually manage the vector as a heap. This wouldn't be too difficult since all the `priority_queue` operations are effectively wrappers around the heap operations found in [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)

Comment: So if you are willing to take the cost of increasing the use count why don't you do: `shared_ptr<T> first( pq.top() )`?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This does **not** increase the use_count.  See [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#copy_constructor) .

Comment: @theTrickster Interesting, in `gcc` and `clang` it does increase the use count, I will have to think about that, using `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @theTrickster I was able to get it to work just fine using `boost::shared_ptr` as well, please see my answer below.

Comment: Hmm... then I wonder why the docs for `shared_ptr(shared_ptr const & r)` say the postcondition is `use_count() == r.use_count()`.  Seems like it should be `r.use_count() + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to take the cost of increasing the `use count` then as far as I can tell both `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` will do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template< typename T >
struct deref_less
{
  //typedef std::shared_ptr<T> P;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> P;
  bool operator()( const P& lhs, const P& rhs ) { return *lhs < *rhs; }
};

int main()
{
   //std::priority_queue< std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> >, deref_less< int >  > pq ;
   std::priority_queue< boost::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<int> >, deref_less< int >  > pq ;

    boost::shared_ptr<int>
      sp1( new int(10)),
      sp2( new int(11)),
      sp3( new int(3))
      ;

      pq.push(sp1) ;
      pq.push(sp2) ;
      pq.push(sp3) ;

      std::cout << *pq.top() << std::endl ;

      std::cout << sp2.use_count() <<std::endl ;

      //std::shared_ptr<int> sp4( pq.top() ) ;
      boost::shared_ptr<int> sp4( pq.top() ) ;

      std::cout << sp2.use_count() <<std::endl ;

      pq.pop() ;

      std::cout << sp2.use_count() <<std::endl ;
      std::cout << *sp4 << std::endl ;
}
```

Online `std` version [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1Kvixl%2422)

Comment: Yup, this works.  I guess the docs were a bit sparse and ambiguous and I misunderstood them.  Thanks @Shafik!

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use the compiler which support std::move?

```
int main()
{       
    std::priority_queue<std::string> str_q;
    str_q.push("aaa");
    str_q.push("bbb");
    str_q.push("ccc");
    std::string strs[3];

    strs[0] = std::move(const_cast<std::string&>(str_q.top()));
    std::cout<<str_q.top()<<std::endl;
    str_q.pop();
    strs[1] = std::move(const_cast<std::string&>(str_q.top()));
    std::cout<<str_q.top()<<std::endl;
    str_q.pop();
    strs[2] = std::move(const_cast<std::string&>(str_q.top()));
    std::cout<<str_q.top()<<std::endl;
    str_q.pop();

    for(auto const &data : strs){
        std::cout<<data<<std::endl;
    }            

    return 0;
}
```

edit the answer since the return type is std::string const&, it can't be moved
atleast we cast away the constness.

Comment: `top` returns a const reference which cannot be moved, or at least would require a `const_cast`.

Comment: It is very dangerous because the underlying object will be deleted twice.

Comment: Hi, grep, according what I know, the object after move could be deleted without any problem, the resource of the original one(priority_queue) are transfer to strs already.Correct me if I am wrong, thank you.

Comment: const_cast makes me nervous :), especially since my compiler is not up to C++11 yet, so I'd be relying on the boost::move emulation library.

Answer (score 0):

With `fibonacci_heap`, you may use ordered iterators and keep the elements in heap until you are done.

```
auto it = heap.ordered_begin();
const T& first = *it;  // picking up ref to first element
const T& second = *++it;  // and to second element
analyze(first, second);
heap.pop();  // and now drop them
heap.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks, @grep.  That's good to know.  However, I just edited my question to say that I'd prefer to not have to keep track of what I still haven't popped.